# Linux grep String Search

Tags: linux, string, grep

I want to search

`$GLOBALS["\x61\156\x75\156\x61"]`  using grep but `"` and `/` not working perfectly.

```
grep -rl "$GLOBALS["\x61\156\x75\156\x61"]" <filename>
```

`$GLOBALS["\x61\156\x75\156\x61"]` is a virus malware starting code, lots of files are affected. I have a script through I want search effected files and remove top line

Comment: Are you in a recent version of bash that supports associative arrays, and `GLOBALS` refers to an associative array? Or are you trying to search for literal text equal to `$GLOBALS["\x61\156\x75\156\x61"]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are looking for an exact match and you don't want the expression to be interpreted by `grep`, you have to use `-F` and single quotes to avoid the variable being expanded:

```
grep -Frl '$GLOBALS["\x61\156\x75\156\x61"]' <filename>
      ^   ^                                ^
```

From `man grep`:

> **-F**, --fixed-strings
>
> Interpret  PATTERN  as  a  list  of  fixed strings, separated by
>   newlines, any of which is to be matched.  (-F is specified by POSIX.)

---

See another example of the usage of `-F` together with single quotes:

We create a file like this:

```
$ cat a
hello
${myarray[0]}
bye
```

And an array:

```
$ myarray=('hello' 'how' 'are' 'you')
```

Let's use single quotes and look for the value:

```
$ grep '${myarray[0]}' a
$
```

Let's use fixed string with double quotes -> it gets interpreted!

```
$ grep -F "${myarray[0]}" a
hello
```

Let's use `-F` and single quotes:

```
$ grep -F '${myarray[0]}' a
${myarray[0]}                    #this works!
```